# Correct pattern to extract #define names by sed

Tags: regex, macos, sed

Can't define working pattern for sed. The main idea is to extract only #define's with values, not with macroses from line like one -

```
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_MASK        0xff000000.
```

Sample in shell script:

```
pattern="#define (${toRemove})([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[^\(\)]+\s.*"
sed -n -E "s/$pattern/\t\tINSERT_ELEMENT(${enumName}::_\2, \2);/p" $*
```

Problem is sed ignores following lines:

```
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_VAX_ALL     ((cpu_subtype_t) 0)
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_VAX780      ((cpu_subtype_t) 1)
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_VAX785      ((cpu_subtype_t) 2)
```

...
But I expect it will ignore other lines:

```
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_INTEL(f, m) ((cpu_subtype_t) (f) + ((m) << 4))
```

So I can't figure out what is wrong

Comment: What sed version and operating system are you using?

Comment: Using sed on macos monterey, but I can't see the version, because it has no --version option. Also I noticed that online verison of sed - https://sed.js.org/ has more predictable behavior

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that \s is not working in sed(potentially, \s is for other regex syntax) but [ ]+ works! Tried another pattern to match, without negating:
pattern="#define (${toRemove})([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)[ ]+.*"
Finally, it works!